# How to show the height transition on dynamic images - react css

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-animations

I am working on showing multiple images as a slide. Image height is dynamic, not static. I just want to show the animation on the height transition when moving to the next image.

this is my parent div container.

```
<div style={ {height: '100%',margin: '0px',width: '100%',transition:'height 2s',}}>
    <ImageSlide
      url={this.images[currentImageIndex]}
    />
</div>
```

this is my Image slide component.

```
<div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <img style={width: '100%',display: 'inline-block',transition: 'height 2s',} alt=" " src={url} />
</div>
```

How can I render a height transition animation while moving to next image?

Comment: The transition will only make sense if the height attribute actually changes. By default, image height is `auto`. So there is not change to be animated. If you set an explicit css `height` value, the transition will show. You can use a `onload` callback on the image element and calculate the actual height and cause a render using `setState` in your ImageSlide component. You only need `transition` in the dom element where you change the `height` property.

Comment: you mean the height in image tag?

Comment: I mean height css property of the image style tag (eg. `style="{height: 500px;}"`). `transition` applies to css properties, not the dom element property

Comment: yeah, but I don't know the height of the image.it has dynamic height.what should I do?

Comment: Use a `onload` callback on the image. Once it's loaded you can access the `naturalHeight`, `naturalWidth` that represents the full size of the image, and also `width` and `height` which is the rendered size of the element. Then you can calculate the new height and change your components state to update the style.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution #1 - max-height**

When working with non-pixel sizes like `auto` or '%' and transition you can rely on `max-height` property in order to obtain a transition.

Disavantages:

- we still have to hard-code a maximum height for the element, even if we don't have to hard-code the height itself
- the transition length will not actually be what you specify unless the content height works out to be exactly the same as max-height

**Solution #2 - ScaleY**

An other solution is to rely on transform `ScaleY`. We set a transition for the element's transform property, then toggle between transform: scaleY(1) and transform: scaleY(0). These mean, respectively, "render this element at the same scale (on the y axis) that it starts out at" and "render this element at a scale of 0 (on the y axis)". Transitioning between these two states will neatly "squish" the element to and from its natural, content-based size. As a bonus, even the letters and/or images inside will visually "squish" themselves, rather than sliding behind the element's boundary. The downside? Since no reflow is triggered, the elements around this element will be completely unaffected. They will neither move nor resize to fill in the empty space.

Ref and examples: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: If you don't want squishing of images, you can use the css `object-fit` property and set to `cover` to crop the image to fit the image element dimensions during transition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: There is also a flex solution in the link. Personally I would resolve with a verticalized Image component that automanage load, size, visibility and transition

Comment: sure I will look at it.here I don't know the height of the images.

Comment: If it can help: https://blog.logrocket.com/building-size-aware-react-components-b4c37e7d96e7, https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme ,  https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-resize-aware